How to properly manage a boolean signal input in a custom Angular element (v19)?
I have a web component created with Angular 19 prerelease version. It has a liked signal input, which can be set from a parent but can't be modified from within because signal inputs are read only. To manage toggling the state, I introduced a local signal _liked, which I can toggle and emit its value to the parent. This feels like an overkill, I'm not sure if this is a good way of handling the state.
I need to transform the input value into a boolean, because when the custom element is used outside Angular context, say in a Vue app, the resulting html will render my input as a string and strings are always truthy.
Do you have any suggestions on improving the following code?
export class LikeButtonComponent {
    liked = input(false, { transform: booleanAttribute });
    _liked = signal(this.liked());
    
    likedChange = output<boolean>({ alias: 'likedchange' });
    
    constructor() {
        effect(() => {
            this._liked.set(this.liked());
        });
    }
    
    toggleLike() {
        this._liked.update(value => !value);
        this.likedChange.emit(this._liked());
    }
}

I looked into the model() and it doesn't seem to be suitable here because it doesn't expose a transform option. The problem is that when values are passed into a web component they are passed as strings, like this <like-button liked="true"></like-button>.

Since Angular 19 you can use the new linkedSignal() function which is basically a computed that is writable at the same time. It allows you to skip the effect:
export class LikeButtonComponent {
    liked = input(false, { transform: booleanAttribute });
    _liked = linkedSignal(() => this.liked());
    
    likedChange = output<boolean>({ alias: 'likedchange' });
    
    toggleLike() {
        this._liked.update(value => !value);
        this.likedChange.emit(this._liked());
    }
}


As of Angular v19, linkedSignal is in developer preview and might change before becoming stable


linkedSignal() looks much cleaner than effect!

Since using model() instead of input() is not an option in your case, I would refactor your current solution by getting rid of effect():
export class LikeButtonComponent {
    liked = input(false, { transform: booleanAttribute });
    _liked = computed(() => signal(this.liked())); // resets if the external "liked" changes
    
    likedChange = output<boolean>({ alias: 'likedchange' });

    toggleLike() {
        this.likedChange.emit(this._liked());
    }
}

Inspired by: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKxcIQMWSNU&ab_channel=TechStackNation

this looks interesting, need to test it out

It looks like everyone of us is going around the same thing, so I'll try with my approach :)
import {Component, computed, model, output} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-like',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [],
    template: `
        <p>Like status is: {{ this.derived_like() }}</p>
        <button (click)="changeState()">Toggle like</button>
    `
})
export class LikeComponent {
    like_state = model<boolean | string>(false);
    derived_like = computed<boolean>(
        (): boolean => {
            if (typeof this.like_state() === 'string') {
                return this.like_state() === 'true';
            } else {
                return <boolean>this.like_state();
            }
        });

    emit_like = output<boolean>();

    changeState() {
        this.like_state.set(!this.like_state());
        this.emit_like.emit(this.derived_like());
    }
}


For the input I used a model so that I can change the state from inside.
I checked the type of the input in the computed derived_like so that I don't need to transform the input and I'm sure that the output will always be a boolean.

I believe you can't set signal values inside computed. Also, If you do find a way to set a boolean value in the model this might end up with an infinite loop, as the component will continuously try to set the value to boolean from the inside but receive a string from the outside

@YuliaGaliulina You're right. I modified the first part of the computed property and now it handles both the string and the boolean input cases.
